# Pop-up blocks on all browser in jquery on dynamic button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to open a url in a new tab. Url comes from ajax request on success url return and want to open in a new tab. Currently chrome gives an message `popup blocked`. 
Here is my HTML Code:

```
<input type="button" id="btnTest" onclick="GetLink()" value="Test" />
```

click on this button and call the ajax request. return url below is my js code

```
function GetLink() {       
        $.post('@Url.Action("GetUrl", "TestController")', {
            Id: $('#Id').val(),
            Id1: $('#Id1').val(),
            Id2: $('#Id2').val()
        }).done(function (data) {

            var a = document.createElement("a");
            a.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
                a.href = data;
                a.target = '_blank';
                return false;
            });

            a.click();          
        });
    }
```

image for popup blocked

[image]

i create a button and then click this buttton. It's give me message Popups Blocked. Please help me to get rid off this issue..

Comment: Have you umm tried clicking  where it says Popups blocked and allowing popups? Like are you talking about the built in browser popup blocker? If not, what are you talking about.

Comment: @basic check the image i have add

Comment: haha that is your browser pop-up blocker. Click it and allow popups.

Comment: @basic i don't want to allow from browser. i want to do it from jquery

Comment: I think (not sure) this happens if there is a time gap between the user click and the actual popup (You need to ajax and get the link before you actually open the page)

Comment: @Eddie can you please provide the js fiddle

Comment: Just open `@Url.Action("GetUrl", "TestController")` with URL parameters and redirect it to the new URL?

Comment: @Eddie actually we are hitting a different application by this URL..

Comment: But `@Url.Action("GetUrl", "TestController")` is your application, right?

Comment: @Eddie yes i am getting the another application Url from this action @Url.Action("GetUrl", "TestController")

Comment: Kinda hard to explain in the comment, so I added an answer. I'm not sure if this is what you need. Please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I think the browser blocks the opening of the new tab because there is a delay between the user click and the actual pop up code.

My suggestion is:

```
function GetLink() {       
    var url = '@Url.Action("GetUrl", "TestController")' + "?Id=" + $('#Id').val() + "&Id1=" + $('#Id1').val() + "&Id2=" + $('#Id2').val();
    var win = window.open(url, '_blank');
    win.focus();
}

<input type="button" id="btnTest" onclick="GetLink()" value="Test" />
```

On your `TestController` -> `GetUrl`, get the URL parameters ( `Id`, `Id1` and `Id2` ). Process the data and **redirect** to the new URL.

No need to return the new URL via ajax and open a new tab.